# How to count words in a string in python

Tags: python, count, cpu-word, paragraph

I want to be able to input a word and for python to count the number of words up to that word in a previous paragraph.

This is for a program to help you know how much words you can read in one minute. A paragraph is printed and a timer is set up for one minute. When the minute ends, the user inputs the word they reached in the paragraph and the program must tell you how many words you read up to that one.

```
print ('write start to begin the program')
x = ('')

if x == (''):
    x = input()

if x == 'start':
    import threading 
    def yyy(): 
        print("time is up")
        print('write the last word you read')
        word = input()
        #MISSING CODE

    timer = threading.Timer(10.0, yyy) 
    timer.start()
    print ('paragraph to read')
```

this is shortened but I need a function for python to count the words in the paragraph UP TO the one the user inputs once the time is up and to print that number

Comment: Why do you write `if x == (''):`? What else could it be, since you just assigned it on the previous line? There's also no need to put `()` around `''`.

Comment: Split the paragraph into a list of words. You can then use `words.find(word)` to get the index of the word the user enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split()` to split the paragraph string into a list of words:

```
#paragraph_text = "One two three four"
words = paragraph_text.split(' ')
#words = ["One", "two", "three", "four"]
```

You could then loop through this list, comparing it to the word the user inputted:

```
for counter, candidate in enumerate(words):
    if candidate == word:
        print("You have read %s words!" % (counter + 1))
        #Other actions
        break
```

This is a very simplistic implementation; this will not work if there are duplicate words etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually one may use `str.split()`. But keep away from any parameters as by default it treats all the space characters including `\n\r\t\f`. If `' '` is given as previous answer suggests you may end up with wrong results. Also as stated in help for `split` the write way for natural text is to use regexp.

> split(self, /, sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
> Return a list of the substrings in the string, using sep as the separator string.
>
> ```
>   sep
>     The separator used to split the string.
>
>     When set to None (the default value), will split on any whitespace
>     character (including \n \r \t \f and spaces) and will discard
>     empty strings from the result.
>   maxsplit
>     Maximum number of splits (starting from the left).
>     -1 (the default value) means no limit.
>
> Note, str.split() is mainly useful for data that has been intentionally
> delimited.  With natural text that includes punctuation, consider using
> the regular expression module.
> ```

I would stick with something like this.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def words(text):
    return Counter(re.findall('\w+', text)).total()
```